# What does it mean to Vectorize image?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, vectorization, opencv, python

So, I'm new to computer vision and I was reading article about detecting lines with Hough Transform algorithm(HT). It suggest that it's better to apply HT on vectorized image. I did vectorized image, I mean I converted image from png to svg, but I can not apply HT to vector images

So should I convert svg back to raster and then apply HT? can someone explain please

Comment: You should not use vector drawing formats in computer vision. All those algorithms work on raster images. I have no idea what you read or where, or what this “vectorized image” thing is. Are you sure it’s not about vectorized computation? Why don’t you show where you read this?

Comment: Sorry, here is a link (item 3.2): https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220933144_A_System_to_Detect_Rooms_in_Architectural_Floor_Plan_Images

Comment: to "vectorize" a raster picture (bitmap) means to turn it into a vector description (e.g. SVG). programs like Inkscape can do that. the Hough transform *does* make sense on vector graphics (Hough uses gradients or lines) but an implementation for raster graphics won't handle that. it needs to be an implementation specific to vector graphics.

Comment: check here for vectorizer project : https://github.com/Tw1ddle/geometrize-lib